# Are there any tricks for measuring high voltages (~1000 V) efficiently?

Tags: high-voltage, measurement, voltage-measurement

The simple way to measure voltages above VDD is to use a resistor divider. However, once you get into the 100s of volts these dissipate significant power.

For example, one of my current designs measures up to 400 V using a resistor divider with 2.4 MΩ on the high side and 20 kΩ on the low side. This dissipates 45 mW at the operating voltage of 330 V.

Is there a better way to do this? Here's two that I can think of:

1. Use an op-amp to buffer the ADC, so that a higher resistance divider can be used. This can be kind of complicated without a dual supply, since the signal goes down to GND.
2. Use some kind of high-side switch to only turn on the divider briefly while taking a measurement. This is hard to do safely.

Are there any other ways? Or are either of these ideas easier than I'm making them out to be?

Comment: What sort of power dissipation is reasonable for your application? A negative voltage power source for the opamp can be produced with a switched capacitor voltage inverter (LM2660 comes to mind) if you need to use an opamp to buffer the signal.

Comment: 45mW isn't the end of the world, but this is a small battery powered device so I would hope for more like 5mW.

Comment: An op amp buffer seems the simplest method to me. Just how close to ground does the signal go? There are some op amps out there today that can buffer signals down to millivolts above ground; the LT1178 for instance is guaranteed to output as low as 9 mV under no-load conditions, and as low as 600 μV if you give it an external pulldown resistor to help (higher if it needs to sink significant current, though.) You may not even need a negative power supply for this (not that that's not an option too, as qrk mentions).

Comment: The LTC6084 may also be worth a look. LT/Analog makes a lot of these more obscure parameters searchable, so looking through their parametric search tables might find you some other options--they'll include Maxim parts now too.

Comment: @Drew  Is the voltage DC?  How fast does it vary?  How accurate do you want the measurement to be?  [To rephrase the previous question, can you sacrifice accuracy for convenience?]

Comment: @Drew Consider methods that involve static charge detection. You can see a simple demonstration of the idea [here](https://youtu.be/8BQM_xw2Rfo). But there are simple methods for electrostatic detectors (which will need to be calibrated, of course, but they are cheap and simple to build.) No idea if any of them would help you. But you are casting a wide fishing net. So ...

Comment: Also, when using high-resistance voltage dividers, keep Johnson noise in mind. The higher the resistance, the higher the noise, so you may need to filter some (use a longer integration time on your ADC), even if you have a buffer.

Comment: @NickAlexeev This is DC. Accuracy within 1V would be fine, with a measurement interval of 0.25s.

Answer (score 16):

Battery powered designs prefer voltage dividers with large resistance values.  ADCs want low output impedances.  An expedient way to lower the output impedance of a resistive divider is to add a capacitor in front of an ADC.

This trick works when the high voltage signal is DC, and it doesn't vary quickly.  The voltage divider and the capacitor have an RC time constant.

[image]

A sample&hold capacitor in an ADC tends to be on the order of tens of pF or smaller.  When the ADC samples the signal, it connects temporarily the S&H capacitor to the signal.  If there's an external capacitor much larger than the S&H capacitor, then the large capacitor will quickly supply the small amount of charge for the S&H.  The charge in the external capacitor will replenish through the voltage divider.

Comment: Note that with ADCs can yield good results if the external capacitance is low enough that the input recovers quickly from any disturbance caused by switching the internal cap, or if it's high enough that the voltage can't be measurably disturbed by switching the internal capacitance, but yield bad results with intermediate capacitor values where neither condition applies.

Comment: Suppose, for example, that internal capacitance is 10pF, acquisition time is 1usec, and external resistance is 10K.  With no external capacitance, the RC time constant would be 1/10 of the acquisition time, so any disturbance would decay by a factor of about 22,000 during the acquisition time.  If one were to add 1nF of external capacitance, the disturbance would be reduced by 99%, but it would only decay by about 63% during the acquisition time, leaving a disturbance that was about 0.36% as large as what the *initial* disturbance would have been with no external cap.

Answer (score 12):

Well, why not work it out, eh?  Let's take a look:

**Attempt 1: Just use a bigger divider**

This works, at least within whatever accuracy, leakage, and potentially bandwidth, limitations the system may have.  (Bandwidth isn't exactly trivial, as it happens, but the basic idea is to pair the resistor divider with a capacitor divider; the devil is in the details, quite literally: if you want a solid, flat response, it will take some work.)

Perhaps you're limited by leakage, or at least stated leakage.  For example if the leakage equivalent resistance is 10MΩ, and you want 10 bit accuracy: your divider Thevenin resistance has to be under 10kΩ.

Or perhaps the average leakage amount can be tweaked out, or calibrated, to better than that, but in that case, perhaps the *variance* in leakage, over temperature, manufacture, etc., is of this magnitude, and short of calibrating over that range of conditions (complicated to implement, painstaking to perform?), the same limit applies.

In that case...

**Attempt 2: Is it really leakage?**

Typical SAR ADC inputs, of the sort most often used in MCUs, have a capacitive input characteristic.  The internal circuitry is hard to discuss -- no one reveals their "secret sauce", naturally -- but a typical instance is a series of capacitors, initially charged to VREF; through analog switches, charge conservation, and a comparator, those capacitors are switched together such that their combination matches the input voltage, and that pattern is the digital code in the result register.

Such a scheme can be done by *consuming* the input charge, but often it's done with little change in the input voltage (by perhaps a half an LSB on average).

Thus, the equivalent circuit is some series resistance (mux and switches), shunt capacitance (the sample capacitor(s) plus strays), and an equivalent leakage resistance that depends on sample rate and the previous sample's value.

The reason datasheets state you need a low source resistance, is really that they're after a low *impedance* during the sample period, and low resistance is the least complicated way to achieve that.  But if you can get that voltage into a capacitance of (ADC counts) times the sampling capacitance, the error due to sampling will be at most 1 LSB, then you can wait around until the capacitor's voltage returns to its nominal value (i.e. wait a couple time constants) before sampling again.  And if the above process applies, then it can be sampled repetitively (up to that rate) with very little loss indeed.

That is, consider the equivalent circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxo3CE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

This has SW1 and SW3 tapping briefly, 2µs, inbetween a long delay to the left and right.  `SAMP2` settles quicker, actually, despite being supplied through a 100x larger resistor (of course, the resistor doesn't matter during the sample).  But it does settle to a value about 1% lower than `SAMP1`, because of the charge divider (C3 is only 100x C2).

If we had set the initial value of C2 to some other value, it would pull the result in that direction.  For example, it'll read 1% high if set to 2V initially.

Where it gets tricky, is if you have to measure multiple inputs in sequence.  Most MCUs have a single ADC core (or at least, far fewer than they do `AIN` pins), and a mux to choose among the inputs.  When that mux advances, the initial charge from the previous sample is carried over into the next selection.

This is interesting, actually, in a fundamental way: the mux pushing charge from one port to the next, represents a non-reciprocal function.  That is, charge is moved from channel n to n+1 (in the sequence), but not vice-versa.  It has effect similar to a circulator.  This isn't very useful, let alone helpful for taking measurements, but it does suggest that, if you have a set of high-impedance channels, and if they're all at similar voltages, then sample the first one a couple times (or have a lower-impedance "guard" channel ahead of the set), and you can sample the rest with smaller error (because that error is proportional to the voltage difference between subsequent channels).  If they're all different voltages, I'm afraid there's not much to do but buffer or filter them.

**Attempt 3: Buffer**

If it's inconvenient to reduce the sample rate, or other circuit leakages are dominating error anyway (e.g. a 1M divider with 10-bit error is subject to 1G-magnitude leakages, that can arise easily from mere flux residue), a buffer op-amp can be added.  Presumably this would be paired with an MCU, so, anything 3.3 or 5V rail-to-rail or single-supply type would suffice.  Most likely CMOS for low leakage, and indeed we can find candidates even down in the 10s µA supply current range.  Few if any components are needed, layout area required is tiny, and BOM cost is largely the amp itself.

The buffer does enable us to employ high-impedance techniques like guard rings, where leakage paths are sunk to the op-amp's output, shorting them out before reaching the input and introducing error.  Besides precision resistors (not easily found in GΩ ranges..!), we might also need board rout under components (allow cleaning underneath SMTs, longer creepage path), or even point-to-point wiring on PTFE or porcelain insulators.

**Attempt 4: Switching**

There are ways to switch it from the low side.  High side would indeed be annoying, as you say.

Consider an NMOS with excess Vg applied:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUvEyJ.png)</sup>

[image]

Notice the step as Cds and Cdg discharge, limited by Miller effect and I<sub>S</sub>.  CircuitLab is very basic so it's a linear ramp and flat step here, but real devices will give more... interesting curves.  You do need Vg above the maximum sense voltage, by enough to saturate the MOSFET; high voltage MOSFETs have fairly middling Vgs(th) so I don't think a 5V logic supply would do well; or if so, maybe for less than 1V or so maximum divider output.

**Attempt 5: Esoterica**

Resistance isn't needed at all, if certain assumptions can be made.  Perhaps the supply resets to zero from time to time, and a capacitor divider can be used, with low enough leakage that it doesn't drift too much between resets.  Film or C0G capacitors can be low enough leakage to go for some minutes at a time, within say a 0.1% margin.  Maybe even hours.  Electrometer op-amps are available with fA leakage.

It's not something that can be done in general, but then again, if you have a quite low sample rate, say for something like a battery monitor, you could combine it with a MOSFET and pull-up resistor -- this time just that and nothing else -- to get a peak-to-peak square wave, and by clamping the capacitor divider to GND during the low period, a DC-restore function is obtained.

The C divider is well suited to wideband measurements; at high frequencies, DC doesn't matter, only the changes.  Scope probes are made the same way (again, with resistors in parallel to set the DC level).

Even weirder: suppose we use a semiconductor junction and nothing else.  The capacitance varies with bias voltage, so as long as the C(V) curve is well characterized, we can perform an AC measurement of the capacitance, from the ground end of the device, and infer its total junction voltage that way.  Such *parametric* measurements have shown up from time to time, e.g. AD model 310 op-amp (back in the 1960s), and various electrometers, etc. based on them or the same technique.

We can also consider a traditional electrometer approach, such as a field mill.  In short, an external electric field is turned into AC power with a rotating vane; if we generate an electric field with well-defined geometry, we can measure the voltage no-contact.  This can be useful for especially high voltages.

Comment: Very thorough, thank you!

Comment: On many ADCs, the internal capacitance doesn't seem to be reliably charged to any particular voltage.  I would think it should be fairly simple for an ADC to include a function to precharge the internal capacitance to a specified rail or other reference so as to allow the effect of such capacitance to be measured and compensated for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a voltage divider of higher resistance and a single-supply (or RRIO) CMOS op-amp to buffer the voltage. Since a typical MCU ADC represents a fairly high input impedance it will swing fairly close to ground (probably tens of mV, representing just a few volts at the HV side). An unbuffered ADC input on an MCU does typically source a bit of current at 0V in, and it will vary with the rate at which you read the ADC, so you would need to check that out - they spec it with a resistor to GND, which is not the actual situation you would have.

For example, the [MCP601](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21314g.pdf) is single supply, has an input common mode range that includes ground and has RR output. With a gain of 2 you could use a 100k/24MΩ divider. Or use a RRIO op-amp, 200k low side divider resistor and lose the two gain resistors.

Switching the divider is usually not very practical, you'd need some kind of electronic high-side switch or other means of isolating the input when the divider was off. It could be done with a relay, for example, but 1000V continuous rating may be hard to find at an affordable price and size.

If you really need to read down to zero, you could bias the divider up slightly (a bit more than the worst-case effects from input offset voltage and output swing) and then subtract off that voltage digitally. Still single supply, just another couple resistors. I doubt it's worth the trouble. This method is used in some cheap ammeter modules.

Comment: MOSFET solid state relay (photo MOSFET) might be small and cheap enough for a high side switch.  I concur that justification for a high side switch approach isn't apparent.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Good point. There are some such as AQV258 which appear to be adequately rated. Though strangely the 5kV isolation does not appear to be available with the 1500V load rating.

Answer (score 2):

A trick I learned decades ago from a Tesla coil group:
If you just want to quick and dirty way to make a measurement of high voltages, use the meters built in impedance as part of your voltage divider.

Most multimeters and many panel voltmeters have an input impedance of 10 mega ohm.
Add a 90 mega ohm resistor on top/in series with that, and magically your meter now reads 10x.
Obviously for safety you would put the meter in series on the grounded side, but this trip will work reliably with any measurement system that has a predictable input impedance.

Hope this helps

PS please forgive the lack of any visuals as I am posting this from my phone while I can remember that this is a thing. If I remember I will try to update this when I get home to my computer and can draw some nice visuals

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly an answer but an amendment and caveat.

As others have pointed out, a nowadays rail-to-rail opamp will be able to get the whole input range out of your measurement equipment. I recommend to use specialized high voltage differential input OPA, which are designed for that purpose.
High voltage doesn't mean your OPA input will bear 1 kV, but if you increase the input range you can get two beneficial effects.

- Your OPA will most likely be more robust and more adapted to measuring high voltages, as many HV-D OPAs have extra surge protection.
- The voltage derived from the voltage divider will be greater, so your signal quality will improve over static and all sorts of noise.

Many manufacturers of linear ICs have types with such properties in their catalogue.

However my main concern is some safety consideration. At 1 kV you should make sure you take measures to prevent and confine arcing.

- Divide your resistors into several series resistors of lower value. This is common practice in measuring higher voltages. This will also help dissipate thermal power.
- use big packages, beginning from 1206 or greater.
- consider a milling below the resistors, i.e. a slot in the PCB to increase creepage distance.
- Add one or more track fuses in the divider path to confine an arcing event to a well defined area on the PCB.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the incompatibility of ADC minimum source impedance requirments, and keeping dropper power loss low, you use two discrete current mirrors (presuming these have sufficient accuracy for your purpose).

This will not work when the input voltage is less than say, 5V, but by the sound of it, this should be fine for you.

Pick a load current on your 1000V you are happy with.

Use as many resistors in your dropper chain as you need to provide a current source over your operating range. Five, say, 10M resistors will less stress the parts than a single 50M.

Use a low-side 1:1 current mirror. That current should have as its load a second, high-side current mirror referenced to the supply voltage of the ADC. The second current mirror should be degraded to provide some gain e.g. 10x. Any more than that and you should use an op amp to provide current gain.

The output of this second, degraded current mirror has a 0V referenced load resistor matching the input characteristics preferred by the ADC, and the required peak, scaled voltage so as to avoid saturating the ADC.

If you really need input voltages closer to 0V, use FETs rather than bipolars. The latter are easier to work with than discrete devices in this application.